# What phrase, verb or phrasal verb do you use for describing a situation where someone takes someone's job with guile?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

What phrase, verb or phrasal verb do you use for describing a situation where someone takes someone's job with guile? Can use the phrasal verb *get out*? For example:

> The sly employee **get** his boss **out** of the posision and now he is the boss.

Comment: I don't think one phrasal verb will give you a perfect match.  You may have to construct a phrase.  Forced out or drove out don't necessarily imply stealth or guile.   .

Comment: [*To **oust***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oust) someone has the specific sense of *to force someone to leave a position of power, **job**, place, or competition*. But just because *A ousted B* doesn't necessarily imply that A *took over* B's position - simply that B was forced out.

Comment: You might say "The sly employee undermined his boss to take over his job." But it's not a phrasal verb.